shape inference of TRT::EfficientNMS_TRT type is missing
I trained yolov7 tiny for 4 classes for recognition of face landmarks face, eye, nose and mouth further i am trying to convert .pt --> .onnx and facing this warning
enter image description here
which ig is causing problem in .onnx -->.trt conversion because of not getting desired shape
enter image description here
python : Python 3.8.10
torch : 2.2.0+cu118
also it would be great help if anyone can teach me how to decrease model size while conversion
